# Need to remove unwanted symbols from value using replaceAll method

Tags: groovy

I am getting the value of a field as ["value"]
I  want to print only the  value removing the [ "from the result value.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a JSON array of Strings?  No idea, as you don't provide any context, but you could do:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def valueField = '["value"]'
def result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(valueField).head()

println result
```

Prints `value`

Answer (score 1):

The following script should be what you need

```
def str = '["value"]'
println(str.replaceAll(/\[|\]/,''))
```